# Retrieve lookup values using ClientContext

Tags: csom

I have to search and retrieve the lookup values from the default sharepoint configuration (I'm not sure if this is the real name), for example I have to get the the lookup values of Language, Status, Priority, Country. I need the list of the values because I have to create for example a select box with all the countries, the user will select one and then I will save it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve lookup values, you have to use the ID of the list item used to set the lookup value in the other list.  If I have List A which has a lookup value from List B.  I need the ID of the List B item I am connecting the lookup field from List A.  Lookup values are connected by ID and not by value.